# how to get email body for exchange server on prem using powershell cmdlet

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, powershell-cmdlet

I am looking for cmdlet which would allow me to search and fetch email `body/to/from` information. Currently I am using `Search-Mailbox` but I am getting only the `resultItemCount`. Any idea how to get actual body via cmdlet?

Comment: Why not just export a copy of the mail you are looking for with `Get-Mailbox –ResultSize Unlimited |
    Search-Mailbox -TargetMailbox mailboxname -TargetFolder “MetroFax” -SearchQuery {Subject:"MetroFax"  AND Received:today} -LogLevel Full –SearchDumpster`. That would make a copy of every mail received today with the subject MetroFax into another mailbox. You could then use EWS API to search the results closer if you wanted to.

Comment: right I can do that. The email would be copied into the targetMailbox. But my question more specifically is, is there a cmdlet which I can use to get the email body programmatically using powersheel?

Answer (score 1):

If you use exchange online powershell.

You can identify emails for the past 48 hours ( up to ten days if you specify start and end date).

```
$messages = Get-MessageTrace -SenderAddress anEmail@YourExchange.com -StartDate 03/21/2021 -Enddate 03/31/2021

Get-message -messageId $messages[1].messageid
```

Will return the message from the first one on the list that is returned.

For more info, check out this documentation from microsoftdocs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-message?view=exchange-ps

Answer (score 0):

Are you an exchange admin?? If you are, or have access to exchange admin credentials, I would check out this tool (which is used by hackers to search email) called MailSniper https://github.com/dafthack/MailSniper It is technically for pentesting... but if you wanted to search your emails for body content this would work.

It's a powershell module, pretty easy to use, just download it, go to that directory in powershell, import the module, and start running the commands.  For what you are looking for, some commands to look at are:

- Invoke-SelfSearch (if you're looking for your own mailbox)

  - Invoke-GlobalMailSearch (if you're looking through others' mailboxes)